# Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined when using function()

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

As the title states, I can't figure out why my function authHandler cannot read property 'controls' of undefined eventhough I have defined it. Or rather I think I did - see below.

Would appreciate some fresh eyes on this problem!

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    state = {
        controls: {
            email: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                validationRules: {
                isEmail: true
            },
            touched: false
        },
            password: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                validationRules: {
                minLength: 6
            },
            touched: false
        }
};


authHandler = () => {
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
        const authData = {
            email: this.state.controls.email.value,
            password: this.state.controls.password.value
        };
        this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode);
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.props.onAddUserData(
          this.state.controls.userName.value,
       )
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again")
    })
};
```

Comment: I see two issues, when you use an anonymous lambda block, the `this` pointer is not reset. Second, you're using `this` inside of a function() passed to the Promise. If you `console.log(this)` above `authData` but below the function definition I suspect you'll immediately see what the issue is.

Comment: `this` in your `authHandler` function is the function that you pass to the promise. Turn it into an arrow function and you should be good. Or you can declare `const self = this` above your return and do `self.state.controls`

Comment: Main issue is due to this binding. When you are calling function inside Promise block, you are losing the this binding. Either bind "this" explicitly by using "bind(this)"  or use arrow function throughout and you should be able to get the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've suggested, it's likely you are losing the `this` scope. which you can see if you `console.log(this)`. Here is code that should work. Changing the `function` to a lambda expression won't reset the `this`. Also, the code you posted was missing two `}`s.

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    state = {
        controls: {
            email: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                validationRules: {
                   isEmail: true
                },
                touched: false
            },
            password: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                validationRules: {
                    minLength: 6
                },
                touched: false
            }
       }
    }
};    

authHandler = () => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        const authData = {
            email: this.state.controls.email.value,
            password: this.state.controls.password.value
        };
        this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode);
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.props.onAddUserData(
          this.state.controls.userName.value,
       )
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again")
    })
};
```

or you can do this

```
authHandler = () => {
    // Obtain a reference to this when you enter this function
    var self = this;
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        // Because a function is declared above, this is reset to be
        // that of the function scope, not the one entering authHandler.
        const authData = {
            email: self.state.controls.email.value,
            password: self.state.controls.password.value
        };
        self.props.onTryAuth(authData, self.state.authMode);
    })
    .then(() => {
        self.props.onAddUserData(
          self.state.controls.userName.value,
       )
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again")
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this up!

Comment: Much appreciated guys for the quick response! Silly me for not spotting that mistake.